# Custom formula list data validation

Tags: c#, closedxml

So in excel you can create a data validation rule using a list that is determined by a formula. 
Any know how to do this using C# and ClosedXML?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own collection using `ICollection` or `IList` and implement your rules for add and remove operations.

```
public class myList : IList
{
    private List<string> _list;
    public myList()
    {
        _list = new List<string>();
    }

    public object this[int index] { get => _list[index]; set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public bool IsFixedSize => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public bool IsReadOnly => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public bool IsSynchronized => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public object SyncRoot => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For some operations which don't need any change, implement them using same operation in `_list`, like index setter.